# Php image resize and change orientation doesn't work

Tags: php

Were are using this code to upload an image and resize it and it worked. We added the code to change the rotation of the image. But since we added the code it is not working anymore

Any thoughts?

```
<?php  if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

if (! function_exists('resize_image'))
{   
function resize_image($font, $desti, $x, $y){

// Primer fem resize
    $CI =& get_instance();

    $cfg['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $cfg['source_image'] = $font;
    $cfg['new_image'] = $desti;
    $cfg['master_dim'] = "width";
    $cfg['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $cfg['width'] = $x;
    $cfg['height'] = $y;

    $CI->load->library('image_lib');
    $CI->image_lib->clear();
    $CI->image_lib->initialize($cfg);
    echo "hola9<br>";
    $CI->image_lib->resize();

    // CHANGE ORIENTATION

    $image = file_get_contents($desti);  // agafo contingut de la imatge a partir del path que conté $font
    $exif = exif_read_data($desti);
    echo "hola3<br>";
    if(!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
        switch($exif['Orientation']) {
            case 8:
                $image = imagerotate($image,90,0);
                break;
            case 3:
                $image = imagerotate($image,180,0);
                break;
            case 6:
                $image = imagerotate($image,-90,0);
                break;
        }
    }
    // $image now contains a resource with the image oriented correctly
    /*?>
    */
    file_put_contents($desti, $image);  // poso contingut de la imatge en el path originari (path+nom.jpg)

}
}
```

Comment: @Grant Thanks for your effort to improve the quality of questions. But most of your current suggested edits will be rejected as "too minor". Try to make edits _substantial_.

Answer (score 1):

Put this at the top of your code:

```
ini_set('display_errors','On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

this will let you know of any errors / warnings / notices.